# How can i check if a checkbox is checked on a different asp page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Basically i've got a settings page, and when you check the checkbox, it should hide certain topics on another page...
How would i go about checking whether the checkbox is checked?
Just need ideas on how to approach it.

(ASP and C#)

Thanks,

Becki

Comment: send the value of the checkbox in the form submission...

Comment: If you want selection to be remembered only until user closes browser or logs off, save selection in Session variable every time it is changed and then read it on another page. If you want it to be persisted for longer time save it in cookies.

Comment: use a database ! And store there your settings per user

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this on how to ask a question here in Stackovrflow : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ASP.NET is not Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net c# is checkbox checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173290/asp-net-c-sharp-is-checkbox-checked)

> Specify event for Button Click

```
<asp:Button ID="PublishButton" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="PublishButton_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you can store the return value ie true or false in a session variable. So that every page can know that whethere the particular check box is checked or not. With this you can automate your code. I haven't tried it but it may work i guess. ie.

`if(checkbox.checked)
session["variablename"]=true;// u have to decide
else 
{

// false statement
}
`

Hence this variable session["variablename"] can be accessible in that particular user session about 20mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your setting by ajax call in time periods.

To do this :

1. Settings page changes value from 0 to 1 in your database.
2. Your pages should have jQuery ajax calls to get the latest value of your setting and apply it.

I hope it help.